# Samsung "Scene Optimizer" and EXIF data

Tags: metadata, image-processing, smartphone, samsung

Considering this earlier question [Is it generally accepted that "Samsung 'space zoom' moon shots are fake" and that some cellphones (e.g. S20 Ultra) use AI to add features?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/133003/is-it-generally-accepted-that-samsung-space-zoom-moon-shots-are-fake-and-tha/133004)

Leaving aside the lack of authentication which might leave metadata vulnerable to undetected modification, does Samsung's "Scene Optimizer" leave an unambiguous field in a photograph's EXIF data?

Is there sufficient identification of firmware version etc. that the scope of automatically-applied modifications can be determined for forensic purposes?

Comment: Given that every EXIF field can be modified arbitrarily, anyone relying on them for forensic purposes is probably doing it work; see e.g. [this answer to "How to detect if a photo's metadata has been changed?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/43152/11371).

Comment: @PhilipKendall, yes, that's why I explicitly said "leaving aside the lack of authentication".

Comment: What about "Scene Capture Type"?

Comment: @RomeoNinov What about it? I don't have one and can't find documentation, which is why I'm asking...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, maybe Samsung add specific value to this tag when AI is involved. I neither have Samsung phone so I can't confirm. It's just a speculation.

Comment: @RomeoNinov `SceneCaptureType` can be found in the EXIF specs on [page 69](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624045241if_/http://www.cipa.jp:80/std/documents/e/DC-008-Translation-2019-E.pdf#page=69) and [page 172](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624045241if_/http://www.cipa.jp:80/std/documents/e/DC-008-Translation-2019-E.pdf#page=172) (links via Archive.org)

Comment: Most camera specific metadata is very poorly documented, as camera manufacturers don't release this information.  To figure out if there is a setting, you can try taking a picture with and without Scene Optimizer on.  Then you could try and use exiftool with the [`-u` (`-unknown`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#u--unknown) and compare the two for a possible setting. Use this command  `exiftool -G1 -a -s -u -MakerNotes:all file.jpg`

Comment: @StarGeek Thanks for the reference to the foundation documentation. Neither of those pp have anything about (numeric codes equivalent to) "Scene Optimizer", so I think we have to assume that if use of that feature is recorded at all its encoding is Samsung-specific.